# Get the similar timezone list as in Android Settings app

Tags: java, android, timezone

I've tried with `DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` but I'm getting more than 500 TimeZone ids and TimeZone name , but i want to show TimeZone and name in my list which should be readable same as my device( Nougat version) is showing in Settings.
My device is showing only 88 TimeZones in setting list i want same like that in my application.

`getAvailableIDs()` is giving names like Etc/GMT -5, Etc/GMT -6 etc. These will be confusing for users.

[image: Timezone list in settings]

[image: Timezone list using getAvailableIDs method]

Comment: Which time zones do you want to show in your list? And what difficulty are you having?

Comment: it should list all countries TimeZone .(1)' DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()' gives 500+ TimeZone ids but i want list of countries timeZone name which should be around 88 not too much.(2) It listed some Zones such as'  ETC/GMT-9 'similar to that which not understandable makes user confuse .

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you. Many countries have several time zones in them. See the [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). About 375 time zone IDs are marked as canonical. 25 of them in the `Etc/` domain, taking them out still leaves you with around 350. No big improvement compared to 500.

Comment: thanks @OleV.V. ,but i m looking for the list of TimeZone which is displayed on android device ( Nougat version) in setting which i counted as 88 only .I wanna know is there any way to get only those TimeZone List in android like it displayed on setting (like in first Screenshot )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Timezones shown in Settings can depend on each device and manufacturer. It's just an XML compiled with the Android ROM, you can't access it from a normal app (Settings uses a library integrated with AOSP called SettingsLib but unless you are compiling your app with the Android ROM, you won't have access to this library).

This can look quite disapointing, however, this file doesn't change that much with Android versions and you can just include it in your project (in `res/xml/timezones.xml`), having the same list for every device.

This is the file for [Android 7.1.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-7.1.2_r36/packages/SettingsLib/res/xml/timezones.xml) and this is for [Android 10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r33/packages/SettingsLib/res/xml/timezones.xml) (Android 10 has got just 1 more city compared to Android 7).

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r33/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/datetime/ZoneGetter.java) you can see how Android uses this XML file to get the TimeZones (name + gmt).

Comment: Thanks Abdelilah El Aissaoui